# Send file to print in the background from ruby on rails app

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing

I'm looking to make an app be able to print out a stick on name tag based on some fields that the user has filled out. The catch is that I don't want the user to have to interact with any sort of system print dialog, I just want it to go straight to the printer and print out after they submit.

The other catch here is that this will most likely be run on an iPad, so I will need to try to send this print job over the air either on wifi, somehow to a computer that is usb connected to the printer or over airprint if I can find one that is small enough and supports the right paper.

I've seen some solutions here and there that require the app to run on windows, or to be connected to the printer some how.

I'm not sure if this feat is possible with this setup, but the most important part is being able to print in the background, if the iPad is going to hinder that, there is a case we can make to our client for getting a small, cheap, windows 8 touch tablet instead of an iPad since I know it has a few more capabilities in this area as it seems through my research.

It doesn't matter what version of ruby or rails it's in and I don't care if it's 2 steps or 200, if the user experience is there, I can make a case for the increased work load needed to make something work.

I'm not a very experienced rails developer, but this project is my first big project that is simple enough that I can tackle it. If more information about how their name tag info is being collected I can shed some light on that as well but I don't think it matters. Whatever I'm printing I need the experience to be the above.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://support.vendhq.com/hc/en-us/articles/201378390-Enable-kiosk-silent-printing-for-Google-Chrome-on-Windows-Video- under *2) Kiosk printing for Google Chrome*

Basically this is using Chrome's Kiosk printing mode. So you would have to get a PC for it to work.

The "print dialog" will pop up shortly but then automatically disappear the the document will print.